# Express series by a closed-form expression

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

I have trouble to find a closed-form expression for finite series. 
Before it, let's take into consideration the following very straightforward example: $$S_{n}=\frac{1}{1+r}+\frac{1}{(1+r)^2}+...+\frac{1}{(1+r)^n}.$$ It's clear that $$S_n=\frac{1}{r} \cdot \left[1-\frac{1}{(1+r)^n}\right]$$.

Now let's assume that $r$ isn't constant, in other words, let's assume that we have the following sequence: $$r_1, r_2, ...,r_n.$$ Therefore the $S_n$ is given by $$S_n=\frac{1}{1+r_1}+\frac{1}{(1+r_2)^2}+...+\frac{1}{(1+r_n)^n}.$$
Is it possible to express above mention by a close-form expression? If yes, how?

P.S. One can assume relationship between {$r_i$}s, $i=1,...n$.

Comment: Your last $\displaystyle S_{n}$ expression is already a 'closed expression'. With additional relations between the $\displaystyle\left\{r_{i}\right\}$'s, another 'closed one' will be possible but it's still depending on the particular $\displaystyle\left\{r_{i}\right\}$'s relations.

Comment: @FelixMarin Sorry, I've wrongly used "closed form expression". I mean to calculate partial sum, as mentioned above (example).